# How to study the global stability for this 3D system?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, stability, mathematical-modeling, mathematical-biology

I am studying a biological system (HIV) and arrived at this simplified dynamical system:

\begin{align}
x_1' &= a_1 + a_2x_2 - a_1x_2 - a_4x_1 - a_5\frac{1+a_6x_3}{1+a_7x_3}x_1\\
x_2' &= a_5\frac{1+a_6x_3}{1+a_7x_3}x_1 - a_2x_2\\
x_3' &= a_8x_1 - a_9x_3
\end{align}
Where as the context and notation dictate: all coefficients $a_i$ are strictly positive. I also showed all $x_i$ to be strictly positive and bounded.

I have obtained locally-asymptotically stability for the unique positive fixed point. I also tried various lyapunov functions, but without much luck. I would truly appreciate any idea to approach this problem, perhaps a form of Lyapunov function, a direct method, etc that I should try.

Additionally, I have done extensive numerical simulations, which suggests the positive steady state is globally asymptotically stable.

---

Edit: for those interested in the original system - especially to back up the various claims that I made in my question. **Please note that the parameters do not match to the system in the question**. It's just a convenient way to write the parameters.

\begin{align}
x_1' &= a_1x_2 -a_2x_1\\
x_2' &= -(f(y_2) + a_1) x_2 + a_3x_3 + a_2x_1\\
x_3' &= f(y_2)x_2 - a_3x_3\\
y_1' &= b_1x_2 - (b_2+b_3)y_1\\
y_2' &= b_2y_1 - b_4y_2\\
f(y_2) &= \frac{c_1}{c_2} \frac{1 + c_2(y_2/c_3)^n}{1+(y_2/c_3)^n}.
\end{align}
The only conditions on the parameters are that they are positive and $c_2>1$. Note that the first 3 equations are conservative, hence it can be reduced. And at any time, $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1$. This system is part of a larger system, but is decoupled from the rest.

---

Comment: Are you sure that there is no misprint in the first line? $a_2x_2-a_3x_2$ (with the same $x_2$) in the first line looks suspicious unless it is your way to say that the coefficient at $x_2$ can have arbitrary sign, which would make suspicious your claim about the invariance of the .positive cone.

Comment: @fedja Thank you so much. There is indeed a misprint. $-a_3x_2$ should be $-a_1 x_2$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both bounded above by $1$.

Comment: Ah-oh. The various claims you make about the system do not hold for *general* positive coefficients $a_j$, so, unless you tell us a bit more about your coefficients, it is hard to give you a good advice. Why don't you post the problem exactly as you have it?

Comment: @fedja I added the original system to back up those claims.

Comment: Last stupid question: it looks like the product $b_2y_1b_4y_2$ in the equation for $y_2'$ should actually be the difference. Am I right?

Comment: @fedja Thank you for pointing out that typo!

Answer (score 5):

This is more a long comment than an answer, but I know that a similar problem, also originated from (macromolecular) biology, was studied and solved by Gaetano Fichera, Maria Adelaide Sneider and Jeffreys Wyman. The system of ODEs they studied was the following one
$$
\left\{
\begin{split}
x_1' &= Lc_1^2 - (\rho_1 + 2Lc_1 + Qc_2)x_1 + (P - 2Lc_1)x_2 — Lc_1x_3 + Lx_1^2 \\ &\quad+ (2L + Q)x_1 x_2 + (L + Q)x_1x_3 + Lx_2^2 + Lx_2x_3,\\
\\
x_2' &=Qc_2x_1- \rho_2 x_2 + Nc_1x_3- Qx_1x_2- (N+Q)x_1x_3- Qx_2x_3,\\
\\
x_3' &=Mc_1c_2- Mc_2x_1+\big[\rho_2 - P- M(c_1+c_2)\big]x_2- \big[\rho_3+Nc_1+M(c_1+c_2)\big]x_3\\
&\quad+ Mx_1x_2+ (M+N)x_1x_3+Mx^2_2+(2M+N)x_2x_3 + Mx_2^2.
\end{split}
\right.
$$
where $\rho_1, \rho_2, \rho_3, c_1, c_2 L, M, P, Q$ are positive constants satisfying only the condition $\rho_2 > P$.
 This system of ODEs is related to the behavior of the pigment rhodopsin in the presence of light and the problem studied in [1] (of which [2] is a summary of results) is equivalent to prove the existence of a unique critical point $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3)$ and its asymptotic stability.
I read about this problem from the obituary of Maria Adelaide Sneider and from the "Last lesson" of Gaetano Fichera: the initial condition $x(0)$ was required to belong to a given polyhedron $K\in\Bbb R^3$, and in [1] the existence and uniqueness of a critical point was proven without restriction on the coefficients, while the asymptotic stability was proved only *locally* (and globally only under restrictions on the coefficients). The problem was fully solved only ten years after by Maria Adelaide Sneider in the paper [3], which have been recently digitalized by the Italian Mathematical Union. According to Fichera, she was able to find a continuous Lyapunov function having only piecewise continuous first derivatives: then, by decomposing $\Bbb R^3$ in 16 "pyramidal" regions, she was able to prove that, in the intersection of each of them with the polyhedron $K$, conditions for the global asymptotic stability are attained.

[1] Gaetano Fichera, Maria Adelaide Sneider, Jeffreys Wyman (1977), "On the existence of a steady state in a biological system", Atti della Accademia Nazionale dei Lincei. Memorie. Classe di Scienze Fisiche, Matematiche e Naturali, Serie VII, Sezione III, XIV (1): 1–26, [Zbl 0414.92004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0414.92004).

[2] Gaetano Fichera, Maria Adelaide Sneider,  Jeffreys Wyman (1977a), "[On the existence of a steady state in a biological system](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.74.10.4182)", PNAS, 74 (10): 4182–4184.

[3] Sneider, Maria Adelaide (1988), "[Steady state in a biological system: global asymptotic stability](http://www.bdim.eu/item?id=RLINA_1988_8_82_2_345_0)", Atti della Accademia Nazionale dei Lincei. Rendiconti. Classe di Scienze Fisiche, Matematiche e Naturali, Serie VIII (in Italian), LXXXII (2): 345–352, [MR 1152650](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1152650), [Zbl 0964.92502](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0964.92502).

Comment: Thank you. While they share some similarity, then non-linearity is different. Additionally, the method established in the reference is rather complicated. I believe for the system that I am studying, certain property on its structure can be used to simplify the analysis.

Comment: @Paichu, you're welcome. My "answer" is intended only as a report on a problem similar to the one you are studying, nothing more: and I am sure you will find a method better suited for your problem.