# Global stability question for system with a unique locally-asymptotically-stable steady state

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, stability, mathematical-modeling

I have an ordinary differential system of dimension 3 that contains a locally-asymptotically-stable unique fixed point. Additionally, the system is strictly-positively invariant and bounded.

Now, suppose that I can show the eigenvalues of the linearized system about the fixed point are **strictly real** and negative. This would mean near the equilibrium, the system is a nodal sink. This seems to rule out the possibility of a limit cycle.

Because I think if a limit cycle exists in 3 and higher dimensions; while it does not have to be a surface-like completely surrounding the fixed point, it will surround the fixed point in some directions. This would lead to the trajectories in the respective direction being spiral-like, which is excluded by the strictly real eigenvalues.

If my understanding and reasoning are correct, can I then conclude that the fixed point is globally-asymptotically-stable? If so, please give me some reference on this, perhaps a theorem. If not, could you please suggest some alternatives to address the global stability of such a situation?

Comment: "Additionally, the system is strictly-positively invariant and bounded" can you remind what this means?

Comment: @fedja Yes. For context, I am studying a biological system. So by "strictly-positively invariant", I mean all of the variables are greater than 0 and never becomes negative for all $t > 0$. For "bounded", I mean all variables are bounded by positive constants (<$\infty$) for all $t>0$. If you are interested, the form of the system is presented here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330210/how-to-study-the-global-stability-for-this-3d-system

Comment: In $3$ dimensions, besides fixed points and limit cycles there can be strange attractors.

Comment: I repeat for the second time my comment I made (and once repeated) below your question [Global stability question for system with a unique locally-asymptotically-stable steady state](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204043/global-stability-question-for-system-with-a-unique-locally-asymptotically-stable#comment6597526_3204043) on MSE: What do you understand by a *limit cycle* in 3D, for example? Some surface? Or (as I proposed in my last comment) a limit cycle on the two-dimensional invariant manifold?

Comment: @user539887 Please correct me if I am wrong, I think as long as "the 2D projection" of the limit cycle surrounds the fixed point, then in some directions, the trajectory would be spiral-like.

Comment: In my opinion, there are so many possibilities of the location of a closed orbit in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that there is no hope for results of that type.  I may be wrong, of course.